# PCI Gen 1 device not working on newer Mainboard with Kernel above version 4.10.9

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, pci, hardware-compatibility

Unfortunately, my  LSI MegaRAID SAS 8708EM2 Raid Controller is no longer recognized on my new Server when i use a Kernel version higher than 4.10.9. So on version 4.10.9 it is showing my disks, but after updating to 4.11 it is not detecting the Card in `lspci` and not showing any disks with `lsblk`.
On my old Mainboard the Card was working fine on the newest Kernel. So at first I was thinking its some Bios setting which could fix the problem, but unfortunately i didn't found anything and there must be a Software fix because the old kernel is working fine.
I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to the compatibility of PCI gen 1 and newer Mainboards and not to the Card in particular, since the Card still works fine with the latest driver on the old Kernel.

This is some Systeminfo of the newer System from `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.14.295 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Console: tty 0 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: X470 GAMING PLUS MAX (MS-7B79) v: 3.0 serial: <filter>
           UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: H.D2 date: 09/26/2021
CPU:       Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 L2 cache: 3 MiB
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 88797
           Speed: 3600 MHz min/max: 2200/3700 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3600 2: 2878 3: 2869 4: 3593 5: 3594
           6: 2879 7: 2880 8: 3594 9: 3598 10: 2874 11: 3593 12: 2873
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 730] vendor: ZOTAC driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 27:00.0
           Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 270x69
           Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console for root.
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio vendor: ZOTAC driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 27:00.1
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel
           v: kernel bus ID: 2a:00.4
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.14.295
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI
           port: d000 bus ID: 22:00.0
           IF: enp34s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Device-2: Intel 82572EI Gigabit Ethernet driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: c000 bus ID: 25:00.0
           IF: enp37s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 232.89 GiB used: 39.07 GiB (16.8%)
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT250MX500SSD4 size: 232.89 GiB temp: 33 C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 226.74 GiB used: 39.07 GiB (17.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 3.4 MiB (0.7%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 977 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sda3
Sensors:   Message: No sensors data was found. Is sensors configured?
Info:      Processes: 174 Uptime: 10m Memory: 31.4 GiB used: 624.8 MiB (1.9%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.1
           Packages: 519 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.01
```

`dmesg` on my old Mainboard with a newer Kernel (working):
https://www.pastery.net/uftfdg/

`dmesg` on my newer Mainboard with the same Linux image that worked on the old Mainboard (not working):
https://www.pastery.net/dwumbf/

The first thing I noticed was the difference in the boot line. Could that be the right approach?

`dmesg` on Kernel 4.9.330 (working):

```
[    1.099063] pci 0000:00:03.2: scanning [bus 28-28] behind bridge, pass 0
[    1.099099] pci_bus 0000:28: scanning bus
[    1.099112] pci 0000:28:00.0: [1000:0060] type 00 class 0x010400
[    1.099136] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc940000-0xfc97ffff 64bit]
[    1.099147] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xe000-0xe0ff]
[    1.099164] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc93ffff 64bit]
[    1.099185] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfc980000-0xfc99ffff pref]
[    1.099251] pci 0000:28:00.0: supports D1
[    1.111045] pci_bus 0000:28: fixups for bus
[    1.111045] pci 0000:00:03.2: PCI bridge to [bus 28]
[    1.111049] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    1.111051] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    1.111055] pci_bus 0000:28: bus scan returning with max=28
[    1.111058] pci 0000:00:07.1: scanning [bus 29-29] behind bridge, pass 0
```

`lspci -v` on Kernel 4.9.330:

```
28:00.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 234, IOMMU group 16
    Memory at fc940000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at fc900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at fc980000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [b0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c4] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d4] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [ec] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
    Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
```

`dmesg` on Kernel 4.14.295 (not working):

```
[    0.312039] pci 0000:00:03.2: scanning [bus 28-28] behind bridge, pass 0
[    0.512001] pci_bus 0000:28: scanning bus
[    0.712001] pci_bus 0000:28: fixups for bus
[    0.712001] pci 0000:00:03.2: PCI bridge to [bus 28]
[    0.712005] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.712007] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    0.712011] pci_bus 0000:28: bus scan returning with max=28
[    0.712013] pci 0000:00:07.1: scanning [bus 29-29] behind bridge, pass 0
```

Both comments (`lspci -s 28:00.0` and `lspci -n -s 28:0.0`) return nothing on Kernel 4.14.295.

Unfortunately, I'm a newbie in the area of kernel compiling (I used this tutorial https://askubuntu.com/a/513243) and don't know exactly what modifications I should make to debug better. I thought it would be possible to limit the problem by applying the kernel patches individually and patching the kernel until the card is no longer recognized, unfortunately the approach turned out to be stupid relatively quickly.

I also looked for changes in the change logs https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.10.9 and https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.11.1, but unfortunately I didn't find anything there either.

I am very grateful for every idea that could help Debugging or fixing the issue.

Comment: Any difference related to your hardware between working_kernel_source_distribution_base/drivers/pci/quirks.c and not_working_kernel_source_distribution_base/drivers/pci/quirks.c ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes, here is the diff file https://www.pastery.net/bhwhhg/ of 4.10 and 4.11 that make some changes to the file.

Comment: @MC68020 I compiled the kernel without this patch. Unfortunately still no success.